# Header reading as row from parquet file

Tags: azure-synapse

I am creating external table with parquet file using openrowset in synapse serverless db. I am able to fetch the data header is coming as a row instead of header. And header schema as prep_0, prep_1,... Please how to get my first row as header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-openrowset#read-parquet-files-without-specifying-schema

That query will return a single row from Parquet dataset, while columns will have their names taken from the Parquet header.